# How to Copy a Folder from a TEST App Service to a LIVE App Service on Azure

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, copy, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

In my Azure DevOps Pipeline I would like to copy a folder e.g. Media from 1 environment/app service, say TEST to another environment/app service say Live. The Media folder in TEST may get updated AFTER the Ci/cd build has been deployed to the TEST environment - just to exclude answers that might suggest putting it in Git and including it as a Build artifact.

EDIT - Clarification on using the accepted answer.

My repo contains the given powershell script in the accepted answer as :

`azure/Copy-Media-Test-To-Live.ps1`

I then add the azure folder as an artifact in the build pipeline i.e.

Edit azure-pipelines.yml and Add:

`- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    path: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/azure/
    artifact: azure`

In the release pipeline - reference the script to perform the copy:

`steps:
- task: AzurePowerShell@4
  displayName: 'Azure PowerShell script: FilePath'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'Your subscription '
    ScriptPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_your-artifact-path/azure/Copy-Media-Test-To-Live.ps1'
    azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion`

Comment: Have you tried task `AzureFileCopy`?

Comment: That command looks interesting - however i have no idea how to specify the sourcePath and targetPath - do you have an example script for copying a folder e.g. Media between a Test and Live app service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any application running in an App Service Environment can be managed via Kudu.  Kudu has an API for downloading a ZIP compressed archive of any folder currently deployed to an application.  It can be accessed with a GET request to:

https://{{YOUR-APP-NAME}}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zip/site/{{FOLDER}}

You can use the `Invoke-WebRequest` cmdlet in PowerShell to pull this content to local storage.

You do need to authenticate to use the Kudu API, which is easy in a browser, but when automating is a little more involved.  Please see the following article which details how to retrieve and present a Basic Authorization header, as well as demonstrating how to use the command API to extract a ZIP file using the `Invoke-RestMethod` cmdlet.  Your service principal will need at least contributor access to your applications to get deployment credentials to use in the API calls.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2018/06/26/powershell-script-to-execute-commands-in-scm-website-on-all-instances/

EDIT (Include worked example script):

*If you have multiple subscriptions and the context has not been set properly in the deployment runtime environment, you may need to use `Set-AzContext -Subscription "<SubsciptionName>"` to set the context for getting the WebApp*

```
$srcResGroupName = "Test"
$srcWebAppName = "tstest12"
$srcDirectory = "/site/wwwroot/myFolder/"

$dstResGroupName = "Test"
$dstWebAppName = "tstest123"
$dstDirectory = "/site/wwwroot/myFolder/"

# Get publishing profile for SOURCE application

$srcWebApp = Get-AzWebApp -Name $srcWebAppName -ResourceGroupName $srcResGroupName
[xml]$publishingProfile = Get-AzWebAppPublishingProfile -WebApp $srcWebApp

# Create Base64 authorization header

$username = $publishingProfile.publishData.publishProfile[0].userName
$password = $publishingProfile.publishData.publishProfile[0].userPWD
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $username,$password)))

$apiBaseUrl = "https://$($srcWebApp.Name).scm.azurewebsites.net/api"

# Download the ZIP file to ./tmp.zip

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$apiBaseUrl/zip$($srcDirectory)" `
                    -Headers @{UserAgent="powershell/1.0"; `
                     Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} `
                    -Method GET `
                    -OutFile ./tmp.zip

# Get publishing profile for DESTINATION application

$dstWebApp = Get-AzWebApp -Name $dstWebAppName -ResourceGroupName $dstResGroupName
[xml]$publishingProfile = Get-AzWebAppPublishingProfile -WebApp $dstWebApp

# Create Base64 authorization header

$username = $publishingProfile.publishData.publishProfile[0].userName
$password = $publishingProfile.publishData.publishProfile[0].userPWD
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $username,$password)))

$apiBaseUrl = "https://$($dstWebApp.Name).scm.azurewebsites.net/api"

# Upload and extract the ZIP file

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$apiBaseUrl/zip$($dstDirectory)" `
                    -Headers @{UserAgent="powershell/1.0"; `
                     Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} `
                    -Method PUT `
                    -InFile ./tmp.zip `
                    -ContentType "multipart/form-data"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did some research and thought i could have used kudusync but see no way of running that from a pipeline. I also liked the idea of running Invoke-WebRequest using https://johnblair.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zip/site/wwwroot/media to store the zip file in a powershell variable - but your link does not contain an Invoke-RestMethod example so I'm not clear a) if i can store the zip in a variable and b) if i can unzip from that variable into the Live app service?

Comment: I'm not clear if I need to use an intermediate cloud storage location to store the zip file? I was hoping there would be something simple like a robocopy cmdlet to do it. I'm just amazed that what seems like a trivial task to me requires massive effort.

Comment: Shouldn't need to use an intermediary storage account.  There should be some volatile storage provisioned to the deployment task you can use.  Please see the script I knocked up in my edit.  Tested with local PowerShell.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to do this. I've not tested it yet but read the code and it looks awesome. I had gotten as far as generating the zip file - but had to hard code the username and password from the publish settings - your approach is much much better. I was in the middle of creating a Blob container as I didn't think i could do ./tmp.zip .... I'll post an update when I've had a chance to test it.

Comment: Fantastic - I can confirm that it worked for me on my local Powershell. I'm going to try adding it to my pipeline. I noticed ./tmp.zip is on my local hard drive using local powershell - do you know where this maps to when run in a devops pipeline?, what space is available (im currently using 26mb and set to increase continuously)?  and if i should use a different location?  Also do you know of a way in powershell of deleting the target folder before uploading the zip?

Comment: It depends on whether you use hosted or agent deployment model.  If you haven't deployed any agents yourself then yours will be hosted.  The files for hosted deployments are stored on the agent machine in Azure.  Each deployment triggers the agent to create a directory for the build/release.  In azure this is usually `D:\a\r{x}\{y}`.  It's the same location where the build and release logs are stored.  If you want to cleanup after the zip is deployed you can delete it at the end of the script.  I'm not sure how storage consumption is billed in DevOps.